# Can I extract all key values inside second-level curly braces while ignoring values in the first-level of the curly braces

Tags: json, csv, jq

With JQ I am trying to read/extract the values present in the second-level of the curly braces (.phone, .termination, .duration, while ignoring values present in the first-level of curly braces (12345, 67891 and 78912, which are already repeated inside the second-level braces. Can this be done?

```
{
    "12345":[{
        "phone": "12345",
        "termination": "picked-up",
        "duration": 5
        }],
    "67891":[{
        "phone": "67891",
        "termination": "picked-up",
        "duration": 10
    }],
    "78912":[{
        "phone": "78912",
        "termination": "busy",
        "duration": 0
    }]
}
```

I've tried filtering values by defining the keyword filters that interest me, but I am clearly missing additional first steps. There are the square brackets to consider as well. Ty

```
cat test.json | jq [.phone, .termination, .duration] | less
```

I'd like to have a line containing comma separated values for the three filters described.

```
12345, picked-up, 5,
67891, picked-up, 10,
78912, busy, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the innermost keys are always in the same order, you could use the filter:

```
.[] | [.[][]] | @csv
```

Otherwise:

```
.[][]
| [.phone, .termination, .duration]
| @csv
```

In either case, you'd probably want to use the -r command-line option to yield:

```
"12345","picked-up",5
"67891","picked-up",10
"78912","busy",0
```

### Unquoted

If you want to suppress the quotation marks, you could use the following, again with the -r option:

```
.[] | [.[][]] | join(", ")
```

or:

```
.[][] | "\(.phone), \(.termination), \(.duration)"
```

With the -r command-line option, these last two yield:

```
12345, picked-up, 5
67891, picked-up, 10
78912, busy, 0
```

Comment: I am able to follow your two first suggestions, but I am not entirely sure how the last one works since it leaves quotation marks at the beginning and end of each line.
I tried the following:

    cat test.json | jq -r '.[][] | ["\(.phone.phone), \(.termination)" ] | @csv' > jq_test3.csv

and I get:

    "12345, picked-up"
    "67891, picked-up"
    "78912, busy"